# Spider Error Processing - Python Web Scraping Error

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to Python and very new to web scraping, but I am trying to build a web scraper for this site: https://www.fortune.com/2019/09/23/term-sheet-monday-september-23/

However, my scraper is running into issues before I am even able to get any data from the website. It kicks back:
"2019-12-31 09:37:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing https://www.fortune.com/2019/09/23/term-sheet-monday-september-23/> (referer: None)".

I created a scraper that is very similar that worked well. I cannot figure out why this is happening on this website.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

My spider looks like this:

```
#Import necessary packages
import scrapy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

#Define Spider
class Term_Sheet_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Single_Page_Scraper"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.fortune.com/2019/09/23/term-sheet-monday-september-23/"
        yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse)

    def parse(self,response):
        vc_deals = response.xpath('//*[contains(@target,"_blank")]/text()')
        vc_deals_ext = vc_deals.extract()
        companies = response.css('a[target = "_blank"] > strong::text')
        companies_ext = companies.extract_first()
        dict_vc_2[companies_ext] = vc_deals_ext
        vc_printouts_2.append(companies_ext)

#Define Empty Lists
vc_printouts_2 = []
links_list_2 = []
dict_vc_2 = {}

#Run Spider
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(Term_Sheet_Spider)
process.start()
```

This is what gets outputted from running the code:

```
2019-12-31 09:37:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2019-12-31 09:37:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.1.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2019-12-31 09:37:15 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
2019-12-31 09:37:15 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: aab47f83ef3b5653
2019-12-31 09:37:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-12-31 09:37:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-12-31 09:37:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-12-31 09:37:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-12-31 09:37:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-12-31 09:37:15 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-12-31 09:37:15 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-12-31 09:37:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fortune.com/2019/09/23/term-sheet-monday-september-23/> (referer: None)
2019-12-31 09:37:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.fortune.com/2019/09/23/term-sheet-monday-september-23/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kyles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 238, in xpath
    **kwargs)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1581, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kyles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "<ipython-input-2-440c0105f261>", line 11, in parse
    companies = response.xpath('//a[target = "_blank" > strong::text')
  File "C:\Users\kyles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\response\text.py", line 119, in xpath
    return self.selector.xpath(query, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kyles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 242, in xpath
    six.reraise(ValueError, ValueError(msg), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\kyles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\kyles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 238, in xpath
    **kwargs)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1581, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //a[target = "_blank" > strong::text
2019-12-31 09:37:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-12-31 09:37:16 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 256,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 60503,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.962091,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31, 16, 37, 16, 682486),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/ValueError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31, 16, 37, 15, 720395)}
2019-12-31 09:37:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: it says your selector is wrong, `Invalid expression in //a[target = "_blank" > strong::text` change it to `a[target="_blank"] > strong::text`

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help.